# What is a standard encyclopedia article about clauses?

Tags: reference-request

I would like to get a deep, multifaceted, modern overview of the concept of a “clause”; its nature, characteristics, properties, definition, where it came from, how it came to be, and so on.

What is a standard reference article about the “clause”?

Comment: "Clause" is a term usually reserved for sentences (a simple sentence consists of one clause), as well as their dependent versions, like the bracketed parts of _He thinks [that I should come]; [For her to be late] would be a bad idea._ Clauses can have subjects and verbs (of various forms), and can be introduced by complementizers or conjunctions. Every clause except the main clause is a subordinate clause and must be connected to some other constituent in the sentence (that's what "subordinate" means).

Comment: There is no "standard" encyclopedia article on the topic. There may exist *some* encyclopedia article.

Comment: Linguists differ on all kinds of things, so there is no universally agreed definition. These days, Wikipedia is probably the "standard", which doesn't mean it's the most accurate or best, but the most-read.